# crystal report error

Tags: crystal-reports

i am getting error when i am trying to show crystal report or export. i am not being able to understand reading the error message. i have bind my crystal report with dataset and also properly send crystal report parameter. please help me to fix up the problem.

```
Error Logon failed.
Details: mscorlib : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Tridip_BBA\BBA JOB Board With New Part\reman\TypedDataset\EOD.xsd'.
Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\temp_a82e24f3-3616-46fa-bb17-84e169f5d5e7 {AD3F546E-6C3F-4675-9174-9E6F417D5F08}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
Error CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Logon failed.
Details: mscorlib : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Tridip_BBA\BBA JOB Board With New Part\reman\TypedDataset\EOD.xsd'.
Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\temp_a82e24f3-3616-46fa-bb17-84e169f5d5e7 {AD3F546E-6C3F-4675-9174-9E6F417D5F08}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100F): Logon failed.
Details: mscorlib : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Tridip_BBA\BBA JOB Board With New Part\reman\TypedDataset\EOD.xsd'.
Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\temp_a82e24f3-3616-46fa-bb17-84e169f5d5e7 {AD3F546E-6C3F-4675-9174-9E6F417D5F08}.rpt:
Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters.
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
   at EOD_Schedular.frmMain.GenerateReport(Boolean ViewOnly)
   at EOD_Schedular.frmMain.Generate(Boolean ViewOnly)
Method Name: ThrowDotNetException
```

Comment: That error has to do with the installed fonts

Answer (score 1):

I see `Error Logon failed...incorrect log on parameters`. Did you try **database->verify database**?

Or, take a look at this. Does it sound familiar? [Crystal Report: Unable to connect incorrect log on parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087464/crystal-report-unable-to-connect-incorrect-log-on-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If there are sub reports in this report, then you must explicitly set the datasource for the sub report too. Just setting the entire dataset to main report datasource is not enough.